# Nginx url rewrite does not work

Tags: nginx, https, url-rewriting

I want do redirect all requests from `my.domain.de` to `my.domain.com`, including rewriting *http* to *https*.
The redirection only works with http://my.domain.de which is redirected to https://my.domain.com which is the goal.
When I call https://my.domain.de, it is not redirected.
But when I try to access `my.domain.com` or `http://my.domain.com`, the redirect to *https* scheme fails. Strange, because I used the same rewrite rule for `my.domain.de` before switching to .com domain and it worked.

Here is my nginx.conf file:

```
    # my.domain.de
    server {
            listen 80;
            server_name my.domain.de;
            return 301 https://my.domain.com$request_uri;
    }

    # my.domain.com
    server {
            listen 80;
            listen 443;
            ssl on;

            ssl_certificate /path/to/cert;
            ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key;

            server_name my.domain.com;

             # Url rewrite does not seem to work:
            if ($scheme = http) {
              return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
            }
    }
```

**EDIT:**
Formerly I wrote that the redirect from everything at the .de domain works. Unfortunately, it only works, if I enter http://my.domain.de or without http://
When I use https://my.domain.de, it get a warning because of invalid certificate. So there is also something wrong in the rewrite rule for my.domain.de.

**EDIT2:**
Now I re-installed a cert for my.domain.de, so the only problem I have right know is, that http://my.domain.com is not redirected to https. 
Edited nginx.conf:

```
  # my.domain.de
server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate /path/to/cert.de;
        ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key.de;

        server_name my.domain.de;
        return 301 https://my.domain.com$request_uri;
}

# my.domain.com
server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate /path/to/cert.com;
        ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key.com;

        server_name my.domain.com;

         # Url rewrite does not seem to work:
        if ($scheme = http) {
          return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a certificate for `my.domain.de`? Because without it, you cannot really set up redirection from `https://my.domain.de`.

Comment: No, as my cert for my.domain.de expires soon, I want to redirect it to my,domain.com, as I have a (wildcard) for it. Isn't it possible to do the redirection before the https handshake?

Answer (score 2):

You have SSL enabled for both port 80 and port 443. The use of `ssl on;` is deprecated, use the `ssl` option of the `listen` directive instead.

Use an explicit default server as a "catch-all" to redirect everything that is not `my.domain.com` and any `http` address to `https://my.domain.com`.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 default_server ssl;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/domain.de/cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/domain.de/key;

    return 301 https://my.domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name my.domain.com;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/domain.com/cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/domain.com/key;

    ...
}
```

Note that one server block uses the old certificate and one server block uses the new certificate.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#single_http_https_server) for more.

Comment: Thanks for this. In the document is written, that it could be easier with using two different IPs. BTW: I deleted my former comment accidently, because I could not edit it anymore...  See the edit of my original post.
I removed ssl on with listen 443 ssl like you suggested. Problem is still alive...

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not acceptable to get certificate errors. Anyway, thanks for this.

Comment: I thought I'd give it one more try :-)

Comment: Well, as I wrote in my edited question above, I gave it a try but with an new cert. Strangely, the rewrite from my.domain.com to https://my.domain.com still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

As the rewrite does not work for me and I could not set up a default server block because of other servers on the machine, I finally solved the problem by adding two servers, one for port 80 and one for port 443 of my.domain.com. I did not now that this is possible. So this is my new nginx.conf:

```
  # my.domain.de
  server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/cert.de;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key.de;
    server_name my.domain.de;
    return 301 https://my.domain.com$request_uri;
  }

  # my.domain.com http
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my.domain.com;
    return 301 https://my.domain.com$request_uri;
   }

   # my.domain.com https
   server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/cert.com;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key.com;
    server_name my.domain.com;
  }
```